# MSBuild - Introducing PackageReference based on specific condition

Tags: msbuild

The idea is to pull the referenced project as package if the active/current build configuration is not specified in `BuildConfigurations` metadata. Otherwise it will be added as `ProjectReference`. In this case, `MaterialBalance` and `Pricing` should be pulled as package.

Here is the code;

```
<ItemGroup>
    <CustomProjectReference Include="..\ProjectName.MaterialBalance\ProjectName.MaterialBalance.csproj" PackageName="ProjectName.MaterialBalance" PackageVersion="$(AllVersions)" BuildConfigurations="Debug,Release,Prod,MaterialBalance"/>
    <CustomProjectReference Include="..\ProjectName.Pricing\ProjectName.Pricing.csproj" PackageName="ProjectName.Pricing" PackageVersion="$(AllVersions)" BuildConfigurations="Debug,Release,Prod,Pricing"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

```
<Target Name="SetPackageReferences" BeforeTargets="CollectPackageReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')" Version="%(CustomProjectReference.PackageVersion)" Condition="!$([System.String]::new('%(CustomProjectReference.BuildConfigurations)').Contains('$(Configuration)'))" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

The provided target `SetPackageReferences` is working as expected, the packages are restored and the project is built. But the **Visual Studio Dependency Tree** doesn't work as expected, which I have reported as issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/9415).

I wouldn't have Dependency Tree issue if I could add the package references with my specific condition on **outside of Target/Evaluation-time.**

Do you see any alternative way to achieve **this outside of Target/Evaluation-time** ? On outside of Target, the functions are quite restricted and this doesn't work and requires batch processing;

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')" Version="%(CustomProjectReference.PackageVersion)" Condition="!$([System.String]::new('%(CustomProjectReference.BuildConfigurations)').Contains('$(Configuration)'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: `@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')` is a transform. You are not batching on `PackageName`. The batch is partitioning `@(CustomProjectReference)` by unique combinations of `PackageVersion` and `BuildConfigurations`.

Comment: `$(Configuration)` is generally `Debug` or `Release`. Do you have `Prod`, `MaterialBalance`, and `Pricing` configurations? `ProjectName.Pricing` is a package when `$(Configuration)` is `MaterialBalance`?

Comment: @Jonathan, That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%` character in MSBuild can be confusing. The `%` introduces a metadata reference but the meaning of a metadata reference can be wildly different based on the context.

A metadata reference can be part of a transform expression, a batching selector, or an item self-reference.

### Transform

`@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')` is an example of a [transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-transforms?view=vs-2022).

An item collection reference (e.g. `@(CustomProjectReference)`) optionally accepts a transform and/or a separator.

```
@(<name>[->'<transform-expression>'][, '<separator>'])
```

Given the following message tasks:

```xml
    <Message Text="@(CustomProjectReference)" />
    <Message Text="@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')" />
    <Message Text="@(CustomProjectReference->'name is %(Filename) and ext is %(Extension)')" />
```

The output will be:

```
..\ProjectName.MaterialBalance\ProjectName.MaterialBalance.csproj;..\ProjectName.Pricing\ProjectName.Pricing.csproj
ProjectName.MaterialBalance;ProjectName.Pricing
name is ProjectName.MaterialBalance and ext is .csproj;name is ProjectName.Pricing and ext is .csproj
```

### Batching

Batching (as the original question touched on) is only available to tasks within a target (task batching) and on a target (target batching).

A metadata reference that is not in a transform expression and is within or part of a target is a batching selector. The batching selector is used to partition the item collection into batches.

### Metadata Self-reference

That leaves a metadata reference that is not in a transform expression and is not in a target. This can be used in an Item as a self reference to its own metadata.

### Creating a Sub-set using [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#BKMK_RemoveAttribute) and MatchOnMetadata

The package references need to be available in the [evaluation phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2022) so that the Visual Studio UI can show the references. (Targets are run in the execution phase after the evaluation phase.)

Given

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <CustomProjectReference Include="..\ProjectName.MaterialBalance\ProjectName.MaterialBalance.csproj" PackageName="ProjectName.MaterialBalance" PackageVersion="$(AllVersions)" BuildConfigurations="Debug,Release,Prod,MaterialBalance"/>
    <CustomProjectReference Include="..\ProjectName.Pricing\ProjectName.Pricing.csproj" PackageName="ProjectName.Pricing" PackageVersion="$(AllVersions)" BuildConfigurations="Debug,Release,Prod,Pricing"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

there are two things to acheive:

- Map a `CustomProjectReference` item to a `PackageReference`.
- Filter based on the `$(Configuration)`.

Mapping may look like:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <_tmpPackageRef Include="@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')" Version="%(PackageVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The existing metadata for items in `@(CustomProjectReference)` is carried over. If you put a message task in an appropriate target you can test and see.

```xml
    <Message Text="@(_tmpPackageRef->'%(Identity) %(BuildConfigurations)', '%0d%0a')" />
```

will display

```
ProjectName.MaterialBalance Debug,Release,Prod,MaterialBalance
ProjectName.Pricing Debug,Release,Prod,Pricing
```

When batching can't be used, an item collection can be filtered with [Remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2022#BKMK_RemoveAttribute) and MatchOnMetadata.

Filtering is tricky because the value of the `BuildConfigurations` metadata is a list. But the result of the `Contains()` test can be metadata and can be created when mapping. A `HasConfig` can be added that can be used later to filter. (Note that the negation operator `!` can't be used here because this is not a [`Condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2022).)

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <_tmpPackageRef Include="@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')" Version="%(PackageVersion)" HasConfig="$([System.String]::new('%(BuildConfigurations)').Contains('$(Configuration)'))" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Putting it all together may look like the following:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <_tmpPackageRef Include="@(CustomProjectReference->'%(PackageName)')" Version="%(PackageVersion)" HasConfig="$([System.String]::new('%(BuildConfigurations)').Contains('$(Configuration)'))" />
    <_Tester Include="True" HasConfig="%(Identity)" />
    <_tmpPackageRef Remove="@(_Tester)" MatchOnMetadata="HasConfig" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="@(_tmpPackageRef)" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

The `_Tester` item collection is only for the `Remove`. The purpose of `_Tester` is to provide a `HasConfig` and the value of `Include` could be anything. I chose to include `True` and self reference to set `HasConfig`. The match is for `True` (not `False`) because items that match will be removed leaving only the items where the current value of `$(Configuration)` is not in `BuildConfigurations`.

Comment: This is a brilliant and smart solution, thank you so much !